# regex float and int without comma

Tags: c++, regex, qt

i write a regex for integers and float in Qt (C++)
Now i dont want to match my Input when i write a comma. 
For example:

1. 123.3 --> ok
2. 123   --> ok
3. 123,3 --> NO match

> I tried the following regex:

```
(\d*[.]?\d*)
```

so now i match for:

1. 123.3 --> match: 123.3
2. 123   --> match: 123
3. 123,3 --> match: 123

I dont want to match the regex when i write a comma.
Is this possible?

Comment: try this one `(\d*[.|,]?\d*)`

Comment: @zapredelom Remove `|`, square brackets already "or" all the characters inside. your version would also match `123|456`

Comment: @Thefourthbird what ist the \b at the beginn and at the end? I get an pattern error at https://regex101.com/

Comment: @SonnyBlack I am sorry, I made a mistake. I had a parenthesis too much and I removed the comment. Try this pattern `^\d+(?:\.\d+)?$` See https://regex101.com/r/gj2o10/1

Answer (score 0):

In a regular expression, a period `.` means "match any character". To match a literal period, you need to escape it, as in `\.`. So, something along the lines of

```
\d+(\.\d*)?
```

Comment: when i Input 123,3 i matchwith your regex 123 and 3. So i match 2 numbers. You can try it at https://regex101.com/

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "input with your regex". Show the code where you apply the regex, if you want help with that code.

Comment: try it on https://regex101.com/ … when i enter 1234,3 with your regex i match 2 numbers. The first one is 1234 and the secound is 3. I dont want to match anything when i collect a comma.

Comment: regex101.com by default matches in global mode, applying the expression repeatedly to the whole string. Either change the mode (a button at the far right), or force whole-string match with `^\d+(\.\d*)?$`

Answer (score 0):

Okay, now i find the soulution. 
Sorry :)

I had to add a start and end of line Symbols …

```
^(\d*[.]?\d*)$
```